# What is the POSIX shell version of this bash "while" statement?

Tags: bash, shell, posix

I'm writing (or trying to write) a little program in `POSIX sh` (following the warnings of `ShellCheck`).
I am especially concerned with a WARNING regarding a loop which in POSIX would be wrong given the double brackets.

Could you tell me what the `POSIX sh` version of this code is:

```bsh
 while (( "$#" )); do
    case "$1" in
      [...]
    esac
    shift
 done
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The POSIX-compliant way to write this condition is

```
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
```

As [jesse_b](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/237982/jesse-b) says, if you’re analysing flags, you might want to use [`getopts`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) (which is defined by POSIX) instead.

Comment: I know "getopts" works great for just parsing options, but it starts to crumble if you want to support long options or mix positional options and arguments together.

Comment: @Stephane Why did you add those double quotes?

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak See part of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/116858) for an explanation why this may be necessary.

Comment: @Kusalananda Hello K, I just thought in the case of `$#` it seems rather optional as ShellCheck ignores it, good to know. Thanks.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak ShellCheck _assumes_ that all shells clears `IFS` or that `IFS` doesn't contain digits. I'd consider this a buglet in ShellCheck.

Comment: @Giuseppe POSIX `getopts` does not support long options, but modern shells support long options via `getopts` in a unified way that has been originally been implemented in `getopt(3)` on Solaris. `bash` does not support long options because it uses it's own version of `getopt(3)`. See the Bourne Shell man page http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html (approx. page 48) for a documentation on how long options work. Note that this also works with ksh93 the same way.